# Difference between site[@name='scheduler']" and site[@name='website'] in Site definition

Tags: sitecore-api

What is the use of `<site patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']"` instead of  `<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Sitecore resolves the site for any request it checks every site definition in top-bottom order.

By default Sitecore contains `website` and `scheduler` sites.

`website` site contains empty `hostName` and `rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home"` attributes. Which means that if none of the sites before matches the request, Sitecore will resolve `website` as the current site:

```
<site name="website" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home"... />
<site name="scheduler" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
```

If you patch your custom site before `website`:

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
```

Sitecore will try to resolve it first.

If you patch your custom site before `scheduler`:

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='scheduler']"
```

it will end up after `website` and before `scheduler` so Sitecore will first try to match the request to `website` and if you don't change default settings for `website` site, it will always match `website` site instead of your custom site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.